# AWS CDK deploying changes to swagger keeps old values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm using AWS CDK (v1.100.0) to manage API Gateway deployments.
The endpoint definitions come from a swagger file.
The stack looks something like this:

```
export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const api = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, 'my-api', {
      cloudWatchRole: false,
      endpointTypes: [ EndpointType.REGIONAL ],
      apiDefinition: apigateway.ApiDefinition.fromAsset('path/to/swagger.yaml'),
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'dev',
        etc...
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This correctly creates an API Gateway and stage.

However, whenever I change the swagger file, for example, I change an endpoint method from `POST` to `PUT`, when I redeploy my changes, both the old and the new methods are present (same thing if I do other changes, e.g. modify endpoint path, etc).

Any insight into why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you compare the Cloudformation assets(locate at `cdk.out` by default) generated by CDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Mode` property in `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` which used to default to `overwrite` (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-mode).

However recently the default value was changed from `overwrite` to `merge`

> If you don't specify this property, a default value is chosen. For REST APIs created before March 29, 2021, the default is overwrite. Otherwise, the default value is merge.

This is what's causing this issue.

Unfortunately, this property has not been exposed in the CDK APIs yet. I have raised a GitHub issue, please see https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14436.

In the meantime, a work around (as suggest in the ticket) is:

```js
const api = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, 'my-api', {....});

(api.node.defaultChild as CfnRestApi).addPropertyOverride('Mode', 'overwrite');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-deploy the stage.  You can do this by changing something on the AWS::ApiGatway::Deployment or AWS::ApiGateway::Stage to force it to update or by using a custom lambda function.

Comment: I believe the stage is being redeployed because I see the new method but the old one is also still there, so rather than replacing POST with PUT, it just added the PUT. Both the API gateway resource and stage are updated in this way.

Comment: You can see the new method, but if it's not deployed, obviously it will not work.  If you (just for testing purposes) go into the Gateway console and click Actions-> Deploy API, does it fix the issue?  If so, it's because it wasn't deployed yet.

Comment: The issue is that I can see both the new and the old methods. I can see it both under the Resources tab and the Stages tab. It should have removed the POST and only had the PUT.